# groovy/lang/GroovyObject not found error when running batch_runner.jar on windows in headless mode

Tags: groovy, repast-simphony

I am trying to build a pipeline to generate a service that can set up and run a repast simphony model in a remote machine. Following several posts, it seems that the easiest way to achieve it is by using the batch configuration, together with the batch_runner.jar, as it is explained in [the official documentation](https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastBatchRunsGettingStarted.pdf).

However, when running the following command prompt:

`java -jar batch_runner.jar -hl -r -c path/to/cofnfig.properties`

An exception is thrown:

```
INFO  13:22:33,709 repast.simphony.batch.gui.HeadlessMain - Writing batch run config file to: C:\Users\mpena\RepastSimphony-2.10.0\output\config.props
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at repast.simphony.batch.standalone.StandAloneMain.run(StandAloneMain.java:207)
        at repast.simphony.batch.standalone.StandAloneMain.main(StandAloneMain.java:276)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
        at repast.simphony.batch.gui.HeadlessMain.createAntProject(HeadlessMain.java:87)
        at repast.simphony.batch.gui.HeadlessMain.run(HeadlessMain.java:66)
        at repast.simphony.batch.gui.HeadlessMain.main(HeadlessMain.java:310)
```

Any ideas to solve it?
Btw: I have already included the `-plugin_dir` flag on the command prompt with the plugins directory in the eclipse distribution.

Thank you!

Comment: obviously "groovy" libraries are missing in a classpath.

Comment: And how can I include them by command line?
Please understand that I have been able to run it in batch mode from GUI and the classpath is already generated with what I need, including groovy libreries, or so I believe...

Comment: `java -classpath path/to/groovy/lib/groovy-XYZ.jar -jar ...` possibly you need more then one groovy library... if you have classpath - just include it in java command